# Access `style` of a Component

Tags: material-ui

Using Material-UI v1,

I want to access `root` inside `styles` of the `Button` component, and to use it for a whole other component (an `input`).
Doing `import { styles } from 'material-ui/Button';` doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible? if so, then how?

Comment: You want to change the default styling?

Comment: No, I want to use it for another component.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve this using simply `import { styles } from 'material-ui/Button/Button';`